# System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to read request

Tags: wsdl2apex

Visualforce Error
Help for this Page

```
> System.CalloutException: Web service callout failed: WebService
> returned a SOAP Fault: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException:
> Server was unable to read request. --->
> System.InvalidOperationException: There is an error in XML document
> (1, 2996). ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The specified node
> cannot be inserted as the valid child of this node, because the
> specified node is the wrong type. at
> System.Xml.XmlNode.AppendChild(XmlNode newChild) at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationReader.ReadXmlDocument(Boolean
> wrapped) at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReader1.Read7_CreateOrEditServiceRequests()
> at
> Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.ArrayOfObjectSerializer12.Deserialize(XmlSerializationReader
> reader) at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events) at
> System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader
> xmlReader, String encodingStyle) at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters() ---
> End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.ReadParameters() at
> System.Web.Services.Protocols.WebServiceHandler.CoreProcessRequest()
> faultcode=soap:Client faultactor=
```

### Calling Using APEX Class

```
public boolean upsertServiceRequestsToYardi( String UserName, String Password, String ServerName, String Database, String Platform, String InterfaceEntity, String InterfaceLicense, LIST<Service_Request1__c> sr ){

                XmlStreamWriter writer = new XmlStreamWriter();
                writer.writeStartDocument( 'utf-8', '1.0');
                writer.writeStartElement('', 'ServiceRequests', 'aaa');
                writer.writeAttribute( '', '', 'xmlns', '');

                for( Service_Request1__c s: sr ) {
                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'row', '');
                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'ServiceRequest', '');

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'ServiceRequestId', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'Origin', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('Email');
                    writer.writeEndElement();


                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'PropertyCode', 'xxxx');
                    writer.writeCharacters('anyhome1');
                    writer.writeEndElement();


                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'UnitCode', 'xxxx');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();


                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'TenantCode', 'xxxx');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'VendorCode', 'xxxx');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'ServiceRequestBriefDescription', 'xxxx');
                    writer.writeCharacters('sparking');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'ServiceRequestFullDescription', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('sparking');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'Priority', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('High');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'Category', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('Plumbing');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'SubCategory', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'HasPermissionToEnter', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('True');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'AccessNotes', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'ProblemDescriptionNotes', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'TechnicianNotes', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'TenantCaused', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'RequestorName', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('justin');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'RequestorPhoneNumber', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'RequestorEmail', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'AuthorizedBy', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('');
                    writer.writeEndElement();

                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'CurrentStatus', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('Scheduled');
                    writer.writeEndElement();


                    writer.writeStartElement('', 'Resolution', '');
                    writer.writeCharacters('Good');
                    writer.writeEndElement();


                    writer.writeEndElement(); 
                    writer.writeEndElement(); 

                }

                writer.writeEndElement();  
                writer.writeEndDocument();
                String ServiceRequestXml = writer.getXmlString();
                writer.close();                

                String YardiPropertyId = NULL;
                YardiServiceRequestAPI.ItfServiceRequestsSoap yardiWsdltoApex = new YardiServiceRequestAPI.ItfServiceRequestsSoap();                                                                
                yardiWsdltoApex.CreateOrEditServiceRequests(UserName,Password,ServerName,Database,Platform,YardiPropertyId,InterfaceEntity,InterfaceLicense,ServiceRequestXml);

    return true;
}
```

LInks : https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223thirdparty708dev/webservices/itfservicerequests.asmx

Trying to use CreateOrEditServiceRequests  to prompt answer.

Comment: Can you please provide more informations like your code if you want us to help you ?

Comment: The code generated by wsdl2apex does not emit the correct XML for some of the more complicated XMLSchema constructs in the WSDL. Including a link to the WSDL and indicating which operation you are using might prompt an answer.

Comment: yes sure i can provide you

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information related to this.
Your help will appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use the WSDL from https://www.iyardiasp.com/8223thirdparty708dev/webservices/itfservicerequests.asmx?WSDL I was able to generate the required Apex classes using the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (disclaimer: this is a free tool from the company I work for).

Here is the output for just the CreateOrEditServiceRequests web method.

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
// Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement
// Methods Included: CreateOrEditServiceRequests
// Methods Excluded: GetPropertyConfigurations, GetResident_Search, GetServiceRequest_Search, GetCustomValues, GetServiceRequests, GetVersionNumber, Ping
// Primary Port Class Name: ItfServiceRequestsSoap  
public class tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI {

 public class CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element {
        public String UserName;
        public String Password;
        public String ServerName;
        public String Database;
        public String Platform;
        public String YardiPropertyId;
        public String InterfaceEntity;
        public String InterfaceLicense;
        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml;
        private String[] UserName_type_info = new String[]{'UserName','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] Password_type_info = new String[]{'Password','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] ServerName_type_info = new String[]{'ServerName','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] Database_type_info = new String[]{'Database','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] Platform_type_info = new String[]{'Platform','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] YardiPropertyId_type_info = new String[]{'YardiPropertyId','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] InterfaceEntity_type_info = new String[]{'InterfaceEntity','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] InterfaceLicense_type_info = new String[]{'InterfaceLicense','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] ServiceRequestXml_type_info = new String[]{'ServiceRequestXml','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'UserName','Password','ServerName','Database','Platform','YardiPropertyId','InterfaceEntity','InterfaceLicense','ServiceRequestXml'};
    }

    // Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement
    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element {
        public List<DOM.XmlNode> anyElement;
        private String[] anyElement_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','List<DOM.XmlNode>','0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement'};
    }
    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element {
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
    }
    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element {
        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult;
        private String[] CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_type_info = new String[]{'CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult'};
    }
    public class ItfServiceRequestsSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.iyardiasp.com/8223thirdparty708dev/webservices/itfservicerequests.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI'};

        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element CreateOrEditServiceRequests(String UserName,String Password,String ServerName,String Database,String Platform,String YardiPropertyId,String InterfaceEntity,String InterfaceLicense,tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml) {
            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element request_x = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element();
            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.UserName = UserName;
            request_x.Password = Password;
            request_x.ServerName = ServerName;
            request_x.Database = Database;
            request_x.Platform = Platform;
            request_x.YardiPropertyId = YardiPropertyId;
            request_x.InterfaceEntity = InterfaceEntity;
            request_x.InterfaceLicense = InterfaceLicense;
            request_x.ServiceRequestXml = ServiceRequestXml;
            Map<String, tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests/CreateOrEditServiceRequests',
                'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests',
                'CreateOrEditServiceRequests',
                'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests',
                'CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse',
                'tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the WSDL has a lot of response sequences that use `<s:any/>`. These are problematic for Apex `WebServiceCallout.invoke`.

So here is another version that has the generated HTTP requests. Use the `CreateOrEditServiceRequests_Http` method.

```
//Generated by FuseIT WSDL2Apex (http://www.fuseit.com/Solutions/SFDC-Explorer/Help-WSDL-Parser.aspx)
// Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement
//Methods Included: CreateOrEditServiceRequests
//Methods Excluded: GetPropertyConfigurations, GetResident_Search, GetServiceRequest_Search, GetCustomValues, GetServiceRequests, GetVersionNumber, Ping
// Primary Port Class Name: ItfServiceRequestsSoap  
public class tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI {
    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element {
        public String UserName;
        public String Password;
        public String ServerName;
        public String Database;
        public String Platform;
        public String YardiPropertyId;
        public String InterfaceEntity;
        public String InterfaceLicense;
        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml;
        private String[] UserName_type_info = new String[]{'UserName','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] Password_type_info = new String[]{'Password','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] ServerName_type_info = new String[]{'ServerName','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] Database_type_info = new String[]{'Database','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] Platform_type_info = new String[]{'Platform','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] YardiPropertyId_type_info = new String[]{'YardiPropertyId','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] InterfaceEntity_type_info = new String[]{'InterfaceEntity','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] InterfaceLicense_type_info = new String[]{'InterfaceLicense','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','string','0','1','false'};
        private String[] ServiceRequestXml_type_info = new String[]{'ServiceRequestXml','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'UserName','Password','ServerName','Database','Platform','YardiPropertyId','InterfaceEntity','InterfaceLicense','ServiceRequestXml'};
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element(){
        }
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element(String UserName,String Password,String ServerName,String Database,String Platform,String YardiPropertyId,String InterfaceEntity,String InterfaceLicense,tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml){
            this.UserName = UserName;
            this.Password = Password;
            this.ServerName = ServerName;
            this.Database = Database;
            this.Platform = Platform;
            this.YardiPropertyId = YardiPropertyId;
            this.InterfaceEntity = InterfaceEntity;
            this.InterfaceLicense = InterfaceLicense;
            this.ServiceRequestXml = ServiceRequestXml;
        }
        public void populateXmlNode(Dom.XmlNode outerNode){

            //System.assertEquals('CreateOrEditServiceRequests', outerNode.getName());
            Dom.XmlNode UserNameNode = outerNode.addChildElement('UserName', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            UserNameNode.addTextNode((this.UserName == null) ? '' : this.UserName);
            Dom.XmlNode PasswordNode = outerNode.addChildElement('Password', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            PasswordNode.addTextNode((this.Password == null) ? '' : this.Password);
            Dom.XmlNode ServerNameNode = outerNode.addChildElement('ServerName', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            ServerNameNode.addTextNode((this.ServerName == null) ? '' : this.ServerName);
            Dom.XmlNode DatabaseNode = outerNode.addChildElement('Database', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            DatabaseNode.addTextNode((this.Database == null) ? '' : this.Database);
            Dom.XmlNode PlatformNode = outerNode.addChildElement('Platform', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            PlatformNode.addTextNode((this.Platform == null) ? '' : this.Platform);
            Dom.XmlNode YardiPropertyIdNode = outerNode.addChildElement('YardiPropertyId', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            YardiPropertyIdNode.addTextNode((this.YardiPropertyId == null) ? '' : this.YardiPropertyId);
            Dom.XmlNode InterfaceEntityNode = outerNode.addChildElement('InterfaceEntity', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            InterfaceEntityNode.addTextNode((this.InterfaceEntity == null) ? '' : this.InterfaceEntity);
            Dom.XmlNode InterfaceLicenseNode = outerNode.addChildElement('InterfaceLicense', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            InterfaceLicenseNode.addTextNode((this.InterfaceLicense == null) ? '' : this.InterfaceLicense);

            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXmlObj = this.ServiceRequestXml;
            Dom.XmlNode ServiceRequestXmlNode = outerNode.addChildElement('ServiceRequestXml', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');
            if(ServiceRequestXmlObj != null){
                ServiceRequestXmlObj.populateXmlNode(ServiceRequestXmlNode);
            }
        }
    }

    // Warning: '<xsd:any>' element type has been changed to dataType List<DOM.XmlNode> called anyElement

    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element {
        public List<DOM.XmlNode> anyElement;
        private String[] anyElement_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','List<DOM.XmlNode>','0','1','true'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'anyElement'};
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element(){
        }
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element(DOM.XmlNode responseNode){
            Set<DOM.XmlNode> nodesParsed = new Set<DOM.XmlNode>();

            this.anyElement = new List<DOM.XmlNode>();
            for(DOM.XmlNode childNode: responseNode.getChildElements()){
                if(!nodesParsed.contains(childNode)){
                    this.anyElement.add(childNode);
                }
            }
            //System.debug(this.anyElement);            
        }
        public void populateXmlNode(Dom.XmlNode outerNode){

            List<DOM.XmlNode> anyElementObj = this.anyElement;
            for(DOM.XmlNode anyNode: this.anyElement){
                Dom.XmlNode anyElementNode = outerNode.addChildElement(anyNode.getName(), anyNode.getNamespace(), ''); 
            }
        }
    }
    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element {
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{};
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element(DOM.XmlNode responseNode){
            Set<DOM.XmlNode> nodesParsed = new Set<DOM.XmlNode>();
        }
    }
    public class CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element {
        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult;
        private String[] CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_type_info = new String[]{'CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult','http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','','0','1','false'};
        private String[] apex_schema_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','true','false'};
        private String[] field_order_type_info = new String[]{'CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult'};
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element(){
        }
        public CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element(DOM.XmlNode responseNode){
            Set<DOM.XmlNode> nodesParsed = new Set<DOM.XmlNode>();
            //System.assertEquals('CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse', responseNode.getName());
            DOM.XmlNode CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResultNode = responseNode.getChildElement('CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests');
            if(CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResultNode == null){
                this.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult = null;
            } else{
                tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResultObj = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element(CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResultNode);
                nodesParsed.add(CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResultNode);
                this.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult = CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResultObj;
            }
            //System.debug(this.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult);         
        }
    }
    public class ItfServiceRequestsSoap {
        public String endpoint_x = 'http://www.iyardiasp.com/8223thirdparty708dev/webservices/itfservicerequests.asmx';
        public Map<String,String> inputHttpHeaders_x;
        public Map<String,String> outputHttpHeaders_x;
        public String clientCertName_x;
        public String clientCert_x;
        public String clientCertPasswd_x;
        public Integer timeout_x;
        private String[] ns_map_type_info = new String[]{'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests','tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI'};

        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element CreateOrEditServiceRequests(String UserName,String Password,String ServerName,String Database,String Platform,String YardiPropertyId,String InterfaceEntity,String InterfaceLicense,tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml) {
            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element request_x = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element();
            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element response_x;
            request_x.UserName = UserName;
            request_x.Password = Password;
            request_x.ServerName = ServerName;
            request_x.Database = Database;
            request_x.Platform = Platform;
            request_x.YardiPropertyId = YardiPropertyId;
            request_x.InterfaceEntity = InterfaceEntity;
            request_x.InterfaceLicense = InterfaceLicense;
            request_x.ServiceRequestXml = ServiceRequestXml;
            Map<String, tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element> response_map_x = new Map<String, tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element>();
            response_map_x.put('response_x', response_x);
            WebServiceCallout.invoke(
                this,
                request_x,
                response_map_x,
                new String[]{endpoint_x,
                'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests/CreateOrEditServiceRequests',
                'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests',
                'CreateOrEditServiceRequests',
                'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests',
                'CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse',
                'tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element'}
            );
            response_x = response_map_x.get('response_x');
            return response_x.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult;
        }

        private DOM.XmlNode populateDoc(DOM.Document doc){
            String env = 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/';
            String xsi = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance';
            String xsd = 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema';

            DOM.XmlNode envelope = doc.createRootElement('Envelope', env, 'env');
            envelope.setNamespace('xsd', xsd);
            envelope.setNamespace('xsi', xsi);
            DOM.XmlNode header = envelope.addChildElement('Header', env, '');
            AddHeader(header);
            //System.debug(doc.toXmlString());
            DOM.XmlNode body = envelope.addChildElement('Body', env, '');
            return body;
        }

        private void AddHeader(DOM.XmlNode header){
        }

        public tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element CreateOrEditServiceRequests_Http(String UserName,String Password,String ServerName,String Database,String Platform,String YardiPropertyId,String InterfaceEntity,String InterfaceLicense,tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml) {
            DOM.Document doc = new DOM.Document();
            DOM.XmlNode body = populateDoc(doc);
            DOM.XmlNode methodNode = body.addChildElement('CreateOrEditServiceRequests', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests', '');           
            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element request_x = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_element(UserName,Password,ServerName,Database,Platform,YardiPropertyId,InterfaceEntity,InterfaceLicense,ServiceRequestXml);
            request_x.populateXmlNode(methodNode);

            HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(endpoint_x);
            req.setMethod('POST');
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml; charset=UTF-8');
            req.setHeader('SOAPAction', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests/CreateOrEditServiceRequests');
            req.setBodyDocument(doc);
            //System.debug(req.getBody());
            Http http = new Http();
            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
            //System.debug(res.getBody());
            Dom.Document responseDoc = res.getBodyDocument();
            Dom.XmlNode rootNode = responseDoc.getRootElement();
            Dom.XmlNode bodyNode = rootNode.getChildElement('Body','http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/');
            Dom.XmlNode CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponseNode = bodyNode.getChildElement('CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse', 'http://tempuri.org/YSI.Interfaces.WebServices/ItfServiceRequests');

            tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element response_x = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_element(CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponseNode);
            return response_x.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult;
        }
    }
}
```

Example call from Apex:

```
tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.ItfServiceRequestsSoap serviceProxy = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.ItfServiceRequestsSoap();

// TODO: Set the actual parameters values.
String UserName = '';
String Password = '';
String ServerName = '';
String Database = '';
String Platform = '';
String YardiPropertyId = '';
String InterfaceEntity = '';
String InterfaceLicense = '';
tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element ServiceRequestXml = new tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element();
ServiceRequestXml.anyElement = new List<DOM.XmlNode>();
// TODO: You will need to encode the extra elements as XML.
tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResponse_CreateOrEditServiceRequestsResult_element result = serviceProxy.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_Http(UserName, Password, ServerName, Database, Platform, YardiPropertyId, InterfaceEntity, InterfaceLicense,  ServiceRequestXml);
```

Comment: I have created same class using wsdl2APEX class functionality but i am facing a problem to pass parameters in CreateOrEditServiceRequests method.

I am new to salesforce so i dont have idea how can I pass XML of type tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element to CreateOrEditServiceRequests method.

If possible please please give an example to pass XML to method by creating XML type tempuriOrgYsiInterfacesWebservicesI.CreateOrEditServiceRequests_ServiceRequestXml_element.

Comment: I have used  XmlStreamWriter to create a XML.

Comment: @Vivek I've added an example call to initialise the anyElement list. Do you have example data that gets passed to this method? It will need to be encoded as XML.